# Find in json by key in mysql

Tags: mysql, json, search, mysql-json

I have a json and i want to extract the value of a key. I know the key name but not the location. My json is complex and would look like this in mysql:

```
set @jsonstr:='
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
';
```

For example , I want to search for the key "Acronym". I want either the full path / or directly the value of it ["SGML"] so that i can process it further.

Im doing the below and its returning me null

```
select JSON_Search(@jsonstr,'all', '%Acronym%')
```

My requirements :

- There could be multiple "Acronym" in my json and i just want all of them.
- I dont have the value part , i just know the key
- My json is complex with nested objects and arrays

---

**Edit**

**It worked**, so i now tried with my updated json which looks like

```
    set @jsonstr:='
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"],
                        "Acronym" : "another value"
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
';
```

So now the query

```
select JSON_EXTRACT(@jsonstr,'$**.Acronym')
```

returned

["SGML", "another value"]

But like this I would be unable to fetch the paths of various locations that have my targeted key.

**Ques :**  If i could get a table back with the "key location" as the first column and their respective values in the second column.

Comment: %Acronym% is a invalid path expression..you might want to read the manual again https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html... MySQL's JSON functions are to inmature to parse out multiple `Acronym` elements out the JSON structure specially when the json elements have random unknown key array elements or undefined array length... there isn't a magic JSON_TO_ROWS function

Comment: Looks like JSON_Search looks for values, not keys. So, for instance, `JSON_Search(@jsonstr,'all', 'SGML')` works, but your example doesn't, because `Acronym` is a key name, not a value.

Comment: `JSON_EXTRACT(@jsonstr,'$**.Acronym')` is closer to what you're trying to get hold of

Comment: What @RaymondNijland says is not correct, as the documentation shows. %Acronym% is a valid expression as an argument to JSON_Search, and MySQL's JSON functions appear to be perfectly well suited to this requirement without a magic JSON_TO_ROWS function.

Comment: "What RaymondNijland says is not correct, as the documentation shows. %Acronym% is a valid expression as an argument to JSON_Search" Well what you say is not correct @ChrisLear "To specify a literal % or _ character in the search string, precede it by the escape character" should have been  `\%Acronym\%`

Comment: But he didn't want a literal % or _. He wanted to use % as a wildcard. Didn't he?

Comment: ah down votes... I wonder how "how to get element by id in jquery" like questions get 223456 up votes as if there was some research involved. I posted this question after trying it ,maybe I missed few things. But atleast I'm not the "don't know get element by id question"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want this query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@jsonstr,'$**.Acronym')
```

JSON_Search looks for values in the JSON object. You know the name of the key you are looking for, so all you need is to use the path, which is explained at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-path-syntax.html with examples at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a function that says "give me all the specific paths that match this wildcard-path". So I think the answer to your updated question is no.

Answer (score 1):

It may be late but try this:

```
SET @junkJs:=JSON_OBJECT('a', JSON_OBJECT('b', 'xxxx'));

SET @x:=JSON_SEARCH(replace(@junkJs, '"b":', '"j":"junk", "b":'), 'all', 'junk');

select replace(@x, '.j', '');
```