# mysql - Search for a key within inconsistent json structure

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I know of the functions such as: `JSON_SEARCH()` and `JSON_EXTRACT()` etc. This issue is that I am searching for a key in a json string that is not standardized. for example:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    users
```

and the results could be something like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| name | last | data                          |
+------+------+-------------------------------+
| john | doe  | {"acctNum": "123"}            |
+------+------+-------------------------------+
| john | doe  | {"data":{ "acctNum": "123" }} |
+------+------+-------------------------------+
| jane | doe  | {"data":{ "acctNum": "1234" }}|
+------+------+-------------------------------+
```

so in this example I want to get `john doe` with the acctNum of 123. but, also, the location of the `acctNum` key is different. I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830615/find-in-json-by-key-in-mysql) that you can use: `JSON_SEARCH(data, $**.acctNum)` but I get empty results,

In an ideal world what I would like is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$**.acctNum") = 123
```

and receive

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| name | last | data                          |
+------+------+-------------------------------+
| john | doe  | {"acctNum": "123"}            |
+------+------+-------------------------------+
| john | doe  | {"data":{ "acctNum": "123" }} |
+------+------+-------------------------------+
```

also that in the link that is above finding the key `acctNum` could be extremely nested.

I had tried using the regexp with `SELECT * FROM users WHERE data REGEXP '123';` but as you could imagine then the user `jane doe` will be matched as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search a defined value at any path:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', 123);
```

Search a defined value at a defined path:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', 123) = '$.acctNum'; -- or '$.data.acctNum'
```

Search a defined property name and value at any path:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(data, 'all', 123) LIKE '%.acctNum"%';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29bdfbc106e180b7200e74d8adbd4815)

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. Originally I had the first solution, but, it isn't finding it. still returns an empty set when I know there are 4 entries. After your update to the question the one that worked for me was the 3rd one using `LIKE '%.acctNum"%'` thanks a lot!