# Get the value of a property given the name of a key, within a JSON object

Tags: sql, mysql, json, json-extract, json-table

I'm trying to get the value of a property, contained inside a `JSON` object, satisying the condition that the name of another property matches a specific value.

Let's say I've got the followig JSON object stored in a column:

```
{
"f2": [
    {"name":"f21","value":"foo_21"},
    {"name":"hit","value":"foo_hit"},
    {"name":"f22","value":"foo_22"}
]
}
```

And I'd like to get the value *"foo_hit"* because it's the value matching the given name *"hit"* of the JSON object the value *"foo_hit"* belongs to. Bear in mind that the matching JSON object `{"name":"hit","value":"foo_hit"}` could appear in whatever position within the array.

The expected value to get would be `"foo_hit"` (double quotation marks included).

To accomplish that, I've tried the following sql statements (based on some clues got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830615/find-in-json-by-key-in-mysql)):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (jsonstr JSON);

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
('{"f2": [{"name":"f21","value":"foo_21" }, 
          {"name":"hit","value":"foo_hit"}, 
          {"name":"f22","value":"foo_22" }]}');

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(jsonstr,'$**.name') 
FROM mytable 
WHERE (JSON_EXTRACT(jsonstr,'$**.name')="hit");
```

But the `SELECT` statement produces an empty result.

Any clarification about how to accomplish the targeted task would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause you have `$.**.name` which is wrong. It should be `$**.name`. However, you'll note that that expression returns an array of values for your sample data, and will never `="hit"`. What you're trying to do is quite difficult in MySQL 5.7 and you might want to consider upgrading to MySQL 8

Comment: @Nick: thanks for your help; it was incorrectly typed and, once corrected I've reformulated the problem. In effect, it produces an array of values, and that's not what I want to achieve. I'm using MySQL 8.

Comment: @lemon: updated! And after a clarification, I've reformulated the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) to extract values from your table. This will ensure that your values are correctly linked to your names. Then it's enough to filter your values using the corresponding "*value_*" column.

```
SELECT tab.value_
FROM mytable, 
     JSON_TABLE(mytable.jsonstr->'$.f2',
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (name_  VARCHAR(30) PATH '$.name',
                                value_ VARCHAR(30) PATH '$.value')
               ) AS tab
WHERE tab.name_ = 'hit'
```

"**Output**":

| value_ |
| --- |
| foo_hit |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bbFYKwpgWxgd7KupwJwrfM/0).